# Erro verificar registro existente pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho a seguinte classe PDO :

```
<?php
abstract class database{
    /*Método construtor do banco de dados*/
    private function __construct(){}

    /*Evita que a classe seja clonada*/
    private function __clone(){}

    /*Método que destroi a conexão com banco de dados e remove da memória todas as variáveis setadas*/
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            unset($this->$key);
        }
    }

    private static $dbtype   = "mysql";
    private static $host     = "localhost";
    private static $port     = "3306";
    private static $user     = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $db       = "bd";

    /*Metodos que trazem o conteudo da variavel desejada
    @return   $xxx = conteudo da variavel solicitada*/
    private function getDBType()  {return self::$dbtype;}
    private function getHost()    {return self::$host;}
    private function getPort()    {return self::$port;}
    private function getUser()    {return self::$user;}
    private function getPassword(){return self::$password;}
    private function getDB()      {return self::$db;}

    private function connect(){
        try
        {
            $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType().":host=".$this->getHost().";port=".$this->getPort().";dbname=".$this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
        }
        catch (PDOException $i)
        {
            //se houver exceção, exibe
            die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
        }

        return ($this->conexao);
    }

    private function disconnect(){
        $this->conexao = null;
    }

    /*Método select que retorna um VO ou um array de objetos*/
    public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);

        if(isset($class)){
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,$class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }else{
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método insert que insere valores no banco de dados e retorna o último id inserido*/
    public function insertDB($sql,$params=null){
        $conexao=$this->connect();
        $query=$conexao->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $conexao->lastInsertId() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método update que altera valores do banco de dados e retorna o número de linhas afetadas*/
    public function updateDB($sql,$params=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método delete que excluí valores do banco de dados retorna o número de linhas afetadas*/
    public function deleteDB($sql,$params=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }
}
?>
```

tenho minha classe extendida da clase database. criei uma função para verificar se existe um user com aquele email :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `email` = ?";
```

Passo o array dado com o email e executo :

```
$result = parent::selectDB($sql, $date);
    $qnt = count($result);

if($qnt > 0) {return false;} else {return true;}
```

Porem sempre que não tem registro me retorna :

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

Como poderia fazer para retornar apenas o numero ? E parar de retornar isso ?
Obrigado

Contagem :

```
$qnt =0;
foreach ($lista as $l) {
$qnt++;
}
If($qnt >0 ) { return false;} else {return true; }
```

Comment: Se quer apenas saber o número de registros use um `count()` do sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deve ser o `die()`, pois só ele pode imprimir na tela.

Comment: Qual `die()`? Qual a solução **correta**?

Comment: Esse die().     $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));